# How can I broadcast a Wireless network from my Mac?

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, internet, wireless-access-point, internet-sharing

I have a ethernet connection coming into my mac but no wireless networks around. I have a second mac and an iPad that I want to be able to share the connection.

How can I set up the primary mac with the ethernet connection to share internet out to the other devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to go into System Preferences, then to the Sharing pane. Select "Internet Sharing" from the list on the left, but don't check its checkbox yet. In "Sharing connection from:" choose Ethernet and in "To computers using:" choose "Wi-Fi" or "Airport", depending on what version of OS X you're on. Then check the box next to Internet Sharing. Finally, in the WiFi menu in the menu bar, turn WiFi on and select "Create Network…". Then connect your other devices to that network you just created.